# Is it ok to use Task.Delay for huge time interval in Worker service

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am working on worker service in .NETCore 3.1. I have a requirement of running service twice in a day, nearly every 6 hours.

This is build in code of `ExecuteAsync` which keeps calling

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Can I use `Task.Delay` for this long time or do I need to follow some other approach.

Comment: It would be way better to rely on some scheduling mechanism, where you can define **cron** jobs. With that you would separate your business logic from the scheduling logic.

Comment: @PeterCsala - Thanks for your input. How can I develop schedule?

Comment: There are several scheduler solutions available for .NET Core from [Quartz.NET](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-quartz-net-hosted-service-with-asp-net-core/) to [Coravel](https://www.blog.jamesmichaelhickey.com/NET-Core-Worker-Services-Background-Job-Scheduler-With-Coravel/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Hangfire`. It is free for commercial use and has different types of jobs.

https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: Also https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ and https://fluentscheduler.github.io/